# Flutter iOS 14.0 build error: Failed to register observatory port with mDNS

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, ios14

I am implementing a mobile app using `Flutter`. When I try to run the app on `iOS` real device from `Xcode`, I get this error:

```
[VERBOSE-2:FlutterObservatoryPublisher.mm(115)] Failed to register observatory port with mDNS.
```

The app runs fine as long as the device is connected to the Mac and running from `Xcode`. But when I try to open it from the device Home Screen directly, it crashes.

This issue happens on `iOS 14.0` and higher. It works fine on `iOS 13.x`.

Comment: I am having similar problem right now. The app crashes before it shows the Internet permission screens

Comment: @GIHYUNNAM When I installed it on an iPhone using an ipa build, it worked.

Comment: Thank you! I thought about that too. Because, IPA build doesn't require the permission right?

Comment: Actually I am not sure, but I tried it and it worked with me

Answer (score 38):

Add this property `info.plist`.

```xml
<key>NSBonjourServices</key>
<array>
    <string>_dartobservatory._tcp</string>
</array>
```

Comment: It solved the issue. Thank you good man

Comment: This worked for me as well. I'm using flutter v2.8.1 and the device was on iOS 15.2.

Comment: Can someone explain what exactly above code does? because bellow answer is working as well.

Comment: Maybe reference to: https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup#local-network-privacy-permissions

Comment: This solution save alot of time

Comment: I am seeing. this in the docs as
_dartVmService._tcp and not _dartobservatory._tcp I think it has been updated

Answer (score 7):

**I was able to fix it**. This is how I did it.

For you to fix this error. open the iPhone simulator then run your flutter project. then go to **System Preferences > Security & Privacy > General Tab**. You need to give permission to iproxy(I can't remember the file name but you need to give that file permission to run). After it has successfully run on your simulator. Plug your iPhone follow the steps again.

Comment: What about a physical device? Where can I enable the iproxy?

Answer (score 2):

## Flutter Official Documentation

According the Flutter [official documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup#local-network-privacy-permissions):

> On iOS 14 and higher, enable the Dart multicast DNS service in the Debug version of your app...

One way to do this is to maintain a separate copy of your app’s Info.plist per build configuration.

1. Rename your app’s Info.plist to Info-Debug.plist. Make a copy of it called Info-Release.plist and add it to your Xcode project.

[image]

2. In Info-Debug.plist only add the key NSBonjourServices and set the value to an array with the string _dartobservatory._tcp. Note Xcode will display this as “Bonjour services”.

[image]

3. In your target’s build settings, change the Info.plist File (INFOPLIST_FILE) setting path from path/to/Info.plist to path/to/Info-$(CONFIGURATION).plist.

[image]

Comment: Docs now use 
_dartVmService._tcp and not _dartobservatory._tcp

Answer (score 1):

I debug an (object-c based) flutter project, I like to launch it in Xcode, I find it more fast launching app in Xcode than 'flutter run' command in terminal. then I like to 'flutter attach' to it for hot reload.

I encountered this error very often.

It seems to touch the AppDelegate.m file forcing it to be re-compiled can fix this problem....

Answer (score 0):

It's a few days I'm dealing (without a solution) with this problem.
If you have any useful information, [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/72161) you can share it (or, maybe, find it).

At the moment, I'm working on a workaround, that I will share in that thread ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

[Here is the original documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/ios/project-setup#local-network-privacy-permissions)

On iOS 14 and higher, enable the Dart multicast DNS service in the Debug version of your app to add [debugging functionalities such as hot-reload and DevTools](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/add-to-app/debugging) via `flutter attach`.

In `Info.plist` only add the key `NSBonjourServices` and set the value to an array with the string `_dartobservatory._tcp`. Note Xcode will display this as “Bonjour services”.

Optionally, add the key `NSLocalNetworkUsageDescription` set to your desired customized permission dialog text.

The original documentation mentions that this shouldn't be used in the Release version and also provides some instructions how to enable only for Debug releases.

*Warning: This service must not be enabled in the Release version of your app, or you may experience App Store rejections.*

Answer (score 0):

**None of the provided solutions worked for me.**

I usually code in VS Code, and run my project with `flutter run`. However, this always caused the crash.

To fix it, I opened my Flutter iOS project in Xcode (`xed ios`) and then through the GUI of Xcode hit the big start button ("start active schema" using the Runner).

This then ran without a crash.

*(I was running on a physical iPad)*